# linked output sections overlap in address

Tags: gcc, ld, arm64, linker-scripts

I have this link script test.ld :

```
/* write for machine virt */
ENTRY(_Reset)

MEMORY
{
rm(rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x80000
ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x40000000, LENGTH = 0x40000000
}

SECTIONS
{
 . = 0x10000;
 .startup . : { startup.o(.startup) }
 .text : { *(.text) }
 .data : { *(.data) }
 .bss : { *(.bss COMMON) }
 . = ALIGN(8);
 . = . + 0x1000; /* 4kB of stack memory */
 stack_top = .;
}
```

and startup code startup.s :

```
.section .startup
.global _Reset
_Reset:
ldr x5, stack_top
msr sp_el0, x5
bl c_entry
b .
```

and test.c for print :

```
volatile unsigned int * const UART0DR = (unsigned int *)0x09000000;

void print_uart0(const char *s) {

 while(*s != '\0') { /* Loop until end of string */
 *UART0DR = (unsigned int)(*s); /* Transmit char */
 s++; /* Next char */
 }
}

void c_entry() {
 print_uart0("Hello world!\n");
}
```

This is how I compiled and linked the program.

```
aarch64-elf-as startup.s -o startup.o
aarch64-elf-gcc -c -g test.c -o test.o
aarch64-elf-ld -T test.ld test.o startup.o -o test.elf
aarch64-elf-objcopy -O binary test.elf test.bin
```

When I do objdump for the final result by `aarch64-none-elf-objdump -D test.elf`, I see this result:

```
test.elf:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .startup:

0000000000010000 <_Reset>:
   10000:       58f88405        ldr     x5, 1080 <stack_top>
   10004:       d5184105        msr     sp_el0, x5
   10008:       97ffc00f        bl      44 <c_entry>
   1000c:       14000000        b       1000c <_Reset+0xc>

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <print_uart0>:
   0:   d10043ff        sub     sp, sp, #0x10
   4:   f90007e0        str     x0, [sp, #8]
   8:   14000008        b       28 <print_uart0+0x28>
   c:   f94007e0        ldr     x0, [sp, #8]
  10:   39400001        ldrb    w1, [x0]
  14:   d2a12000        mov     x0, #0x9000000                  // #150994944
  18:   b9000001        str     w1, [x0]
  1c:   f94007e0        ldr     x0, [sp, #8]
  20:   91000400        add     x0, x0, #0x1
  24:   f90007e0        str     x0, [sp, #8]
  28:   f94007e0        ldr     x0, [sp, #8]
  2c:   39400000        ldrb    w0, [x0]
  30:   7100001f        cmp     w0, #0x0
  34:   54fffec1        b.ne    c <print_uart0+0xc>  // b.any
  38:   d503201f        nop
  3c:   910043ff        add     sp, sp, #0x10
  40:   d65f03c0        ret

0000000000000044 <c_entry>:
  44:   a9bf7bfd        stp     x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
  48:   910003fd        mov     x29, sp
  4c:   90000000        adrp    x0, 0 <print_uart0>
  50:   9101c000        add     x0, x0, #0x70
  54:   97ffffeb        bl      0 <print_uart0>
  58:   d503201f        nop
  5c:   a8c17bfd        ldp     x29, x30, [sp], #16
  60:   d65f03c0        ret

Disassembly of section .rodata:

0000000000000068 <UART0DR>:
  68:   09000000        .inst   0x09000000 ; undefined
  6c:   00000000        .inst   0x00000000 ; undefined
  70:   6c6c6548        ldnp    d8, d25, [x10, #-320]
  74:   6f77206f        umlal2  v15.4s, v3.8h, v7.h[3]
  78:   21646c72        .inst   0x21646c72 ; undefined
  7c:   Address 0x000000000000007c is out of bounds.
```

I don't know why the _Reset is located rightly at 0x10000, but the print_uart0 and c_entry functions are located at 0x00000000. According to the linker script, shouldn't the .text section placed right after the .startup section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_Reset` is located at `0x10000` because your script explicitly requested it with the  `. = 0x10000;` statement.

And you probably should tell the linker that `.startup` should be put with, and at the beginning at, all `.text` related stuff:

```
/* write for machine virt */
ENTRY(_Reset)

MEMORY
{
rm(rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x80000
ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x40000000, LENGTH = 0x40000000
}

SECTIONS
{
 .text : {
  *(.startup)
  *(.text)
  }
 .data : { *(.data) }
 .bss : { *(.bss COMMON) }
 . = ALIGN(8);
 . = . + 0x1000; /* 4kB of stack memory */
 stack_top = .;
}
```

The result will be:

```
test.elf:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <_Reset>:
   0:   58008485    ldr x5, 1090 <stack_top>
   4:   d5184105    msr sp_el0, x5
   8:   94000014    bl  58 <c_entry>
   c:   14000000    b   c <_Reset+0xc>

0000000000000010 <print_uart0>:
  10:   d10043ff    sub sp, sp, #0x10
  14:   f90007e0    str x0, [sp, #8]
  18:   14000008    b   38 <print_uart0+0x28>
  1c:   f94007e0    ldr x0, [sp, #8]
  20:   39400001    ldrb    w1, [x0]
  24:   d2a12000    mov x0, #0x9000000              // #150994944
  28:   b9000001    str w1, [x0]
  2c:   f94007e0    ldr x0, [sp, #8]
  30:   91000400    add x0, x0, #0x1
  34:   f90007e0    str x0, [sp, #8]
  38:   f94007e0    ldr x0, [sp, #8]
  3c:   39400000    ldrb    w0, [x0]
  40:   7100001f    cmp w0, #0x0
  44:   54fffec1    b.ne    1c <print_uart0+0xc>  // b.any
  48:   d503201f    nop
  4c:   d503201f    nop
  50:   910043ff    add sp, sp, #0x10
  54:   d65f03c0    ret

0000000000000058 <c_entry>:
  58:   a9bf7bfd    stp x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
  5c:   910003fd    mov x29, sp
  60:   90000000    adrp    x0, 0 <_Reset>
  64:   91020000    add x0, x0, #0x80
  68:   97ffffea    bl  10 <print_uart0>
  6c:   d503201f    nop
  70:   a8c17bfd    ldp x29, x30, [sp], #16
  74:   d65f03c0    ret

Disassembly of section .rodata:

0000000000000078 <UART0DR>:
  78:   09000000    .inst   0x09000000 ; undefined
  7c:   00000000    udf #0
  80:   6c6c6548    ldnp    d8, d25, [x10, #-320]
  84:   6f77206f    umlal2  v15.4s, v3.8h, v7.h[3]
  88:   21646c72    .inst   0x21646c72 ; undefined
  8c:   Address 0x000000000000008c is out of bounds.
```

Please note that if you want your code to start from `0x40000000`, you have to specify it in the linker script by adding  `> ram`  the the definition for the `.text`section (same thing for the `.data` section):

```
/* write for machine virt */
ENTRY(_Reset)

MEMORY
{
rm(rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x80000
ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x40000000, LENGTH = 0x40000000
}

SECTIONS
{
 .text : {
  *(.startup)
  *(.text)
  } > ram
 .data : {
  *(.data)
  } > ram
 .bss : { *(.bss COMMON) }
 . = ALIGN(8);
 . = . + 0x1000; /* 4kB of stack memory */
 stack_top = .;
}
```

The result will then be:

```
test.elf:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000040000000 <_Reset>:
    40000000:   58008485    ldr x5, 40001090 <stack_top>
    40000004:   d5184105    msr sp_el0, x5
    40000008:   94000014    bl  40000058 <c_entry>
    4000000c:   14000000    b   4000000c <_Reset+0xc>

0000000040000010 <print_uart0>:
    40000010:   d10043ff    sub sp, sp, #0x10
    40000014:   f90007e0    str x0, [sp, #8]
    40000018:   14000008    b   40000038 <print_uart0+0x28>
    4000001c:   f94007e0    ldr x0, [sp, #8]
    40000020:   39400001    ldrb    w1, [x0]
    40000024:   d2a12000    mov x0, #0x9000000              // #150994944
    40000028:   b9000001    str w1, [x0]
    4000002c:   f94007e0    ldr x0, [sp, #8]
    40000030:   91000400    add x0, x0, #0x1
    40000034:   f90007e0    str x0, [sp, #8]
    40000038:   f94007e0    ldr x0, [sp, #8]
    4000003c:   39400000    ldrb    w0, [x0]
    40000040:   7100001f    cmp w0, #0x0
    40000044:   54fffec1    b.ne    4000001c <print_uart0+0xc>  // b.any
    40000048:   d503201f    nop
    4000004c:   d503201f    nop
    40000050:   910043ff    add sp, sp, #0x10
    40000054:   d65f03c0    ret

0000000040000058 <c_entry>:
    40000058:   a9bf7bfd    stp x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
    4000005c:   910003fd    mov x29, sp
    40000060:   90000000    adrp    x0, 40000000 <_Reset>
    40000064:   91020000    add x0, x0, #0x80
    40000068:   97ffffea    bl  40000010 <print_uart0>
    4000006c:   d503201f    nop
    40000070:   a8c17bfd    ldp x29, x30, [sp], #16
    40000074:   d65f03c0    ret

Disassembly of section .rodata:

0000000040000078 <UART0DR>:
    40000078:   09000000    .inst   0x09000000 ; undefined
    4000007c:   00000000    udf #0
    40000080:   6c6c6548    ldnp    d8, d25, [x10, #-320]
    40000084:   6f77206f    umlal2  v15.4s, v3.8h, v7.h[3]
    40000088:   21646c72    .inst   0x21646c72 ; undefined
    4000008c:   Address 0x000000004000008c is out of bounds.
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer. I thought  placing .startup . : { startup.o(.startup) }
 .text : { *(.text) } in sequence makes the sections placed adjacent, but maybe it was wrong. Why was the .text section's start address reset to 0x00000000? Sorry, I'll read the GNU linker manual.

Comment: You are missing `> ram` in the definition for the `.text` section: I augmented my answer accordingly. And yes, the manual for GNU ld is always an interesting read.

Comment: I tried your `>ram` version, and the result shows .text `and` .rodata(like Hello World string) were allocated above 0x40000000 sequentially but all other sections(debug_info, debug_abbrev,..debug_frame,..) were each allocated at 0x00000000~ (each starting at 0x00000000, overlapped).  Why did the unspecified default sections allocated all at 0x00000000?  (I'm reading the manual and it sounds like output sections are places sequentially)

Comment: I am assuming that if you don't specify in which memory area a section should reside in , `0x00000000` will be the default. But this  does not really matter, since those sections will never be part of your final `.bin`file, nor loaded from the `.elf` file by `qemu`.